# Why are pdf files not loading in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<a :href = "require('../../assets/pdf/white.pdf')" target = "_blank">White</a>
```

I am trying to let the user load a pdf when he clicks on a link. I tried using `require` as shown in this code snippet, but, I am getting an error that I may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. I searched for this loader but couldn't find it. I even tried writing a normal path without `require`, but, it didn't work either and it just took me to the home page. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you using vue cli? are you trying to bundle the PDF into your vue project? or did you just want a link to a pdf that will download if/when the use clicks on a link?

Comment: I'm using vue cli , I want the user to open the pdf in another tab when he clicks on a button

Comment: just use a regular URL then, pointing to where the pdf is on the server

Comment: I already tried using a normal url but the link took me to the home page

Comment: your http server settings are probably getting in the way

Comment: what I was able to configure now is that I placed the pdf in the public folder and wrote a static url and it worked but I want to open the pdf in another tab not download it